# get value of hidden field set by another function

Tags: javascript

I have a form that has a checkbox that when click, triggers an event in javascript that assigns a value to a hidden field.  However, I cannot access this when I try to validate the form.  It actually causes the entire script to fail.
I've tried to access it with:

```
var hiddenField = document.forms[myForm].elements[hiddenField].value;
```

and with:

```
var hiddenField = document.getElementById('hiddenField').value;
```

and:

```
var hiddenField = document.getElementById('hiddenField');
```

then adding .value to variable when it's actually used in the script.
I've stepped through all of it in firebug and watched the other function assign the appropriate value to the hidden field.  This variable assignment is actually where the script gets killed.
Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: *"where the script gets killed"* In that case it must throw an error message. What is the message?

Comment: Could you post the according html and the (other) javascript?

Comment: Posting some HTML could help

Comment: Is `hiddenField` the id of the hidden field?

Comment: What do you mean validate the form?

Comment: @PHPglue I doubt he meant PHP as the question is only tagged Javascript and the examples given. It's common to validate a form in Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try this:

```
<html>
<body>
    <input id="hiddenField" type="hidden" value="test">

    <script>
        // Sets the hidden field value
        document.getElementById('hiddenField').value = "Hello World";
    </script>
    <script>
        // Reads the hidden field value
        var hiddenFieldvalue = document.getElementById('hiddenField').value;
        // Display. Should be "Hello World"
        alert(hiddenFieldvalue);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> document.getElementById('hiddenField')
> ```

For that to work, the input would need to have an `id` attribute with the value `hiddenField`. It looks like it has a `name` instead.

> ```
> document.forms[myForm].elements[hiddenField]
> ```

Here, both `myForm` and `hiddenField` are JS variables that get evaluated to the property name when you are accessing the properties with [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Member_Operators). I guess you want those names literally. Use either

```
document.forms["myForm"].elements["hiddenField"]
```

or

```
document.forms.myForm.elements.hiddenField
```